# Tableau filter values instead of aggregate

Tags: filtering, aggregate, tableau-api

I have the following sample data

```
Origin       A,  A,  A,  A,  A

Destination  C,  D,  E,  F,  G

Distances    5,  6,  7,  8,  9

Revenue     20, 25, 40, 55, 60
```

What I want to do is filter out all destinations with distances 7 or greater and display the aggregated results in one row.

What I can do so far is get this table:
Origin:  A, A
Destination:  C, D
Revenue:  20, 25

What I want is to display the following table with the Origin and the Sum of the Revenue:
Origin:  A, Revenue:  45

When I apply the filter on Distance, I set it to be At Most 6, which works when I have 'Destination' in the Columns field, but when I take 'Destination' out, then the filter applies itself to all the distances aggregated (35), which would then filter out everything.

How can I get the filter to filter on individual values instead of the aggregate?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Right click the field (on the filter shelf), choose dimension (rather than measure). This will consider individual values of the field, rather than the aggregation (probably sum by default).

Not sure if this will solve your problem, as I didn't understand what you are trying to do. But this is one way to filter individual values rather than the aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

There are several variations possible on the filter shelf that cause different effects, depending on whether the field is set to dimension or measure, and what options are selected on the various tabs of the filter panel, not to mention context filters.

In your specific case, you should simply be able to place the Distance field on the filter shelf to get a row level filter to on include data rows where the Distance value is <= 6